Apache Superset & Keycloak integration
I am currently working on configuring OAuth authentication between Keycloak and Apache Superset. I am encountering an issue where, after entering the credentials on the Keycloak page, I am redirected back to Superset with the message: "The request to sign in was denied."
Below are the configurations I have used:
Keycloak Configuration (Version 23.0.3)
Client Settings
Valid Redirect URIs:
http://localhost:8089/oauth-authorized/keycloak
Web Origins:
http://localhost:8089/%5C*
Apache Superset Configuration (superset_config.py):
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'https://{my_keycloak_domain}/realms/{my_realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/logout'
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = 'Gamma'

OAuth provider configuration for Keycloak
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
{
'name': 'keycloak',
'icon': 'fa-key',
'token_key': 'access_token', # Keycloak uses 'access_token' for the access token
'remote_app': {
'client_id': 'test',
'client_secret': 'dElzstUQqUgQshK23IWWjmNuoe9GgIo8',
'api_base_url': 'https://{my_keycloak_domain}/auth/',
'client_kwargs': {
'scope': 'openid profile email',
},
'base_url': 'https://{my_keycloak_domain}/realms/{my_realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
'request_token_url': None,
'access_token_url': 'https://{my_keycloak_domain}/realms/{my_realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/token',
'authorize_url': 'https://{my_keycloak_domain}/realms/{my_realm_name}/protocol/openid-connect/auth',
},
}
]

Issue Description
After entering the credentials in the Keycloak login page, the redirection to Superset results in the following message:
"The request to sign in was denied."
I am unsure what might be causing this error and would greatly appreciate your assistance in identifying and resolving the issue.
Has anyone had any similar issues?
I tried various configurations and have been debugging already for some hours.
It seems to be connected in the first place (it redirects to Keycloak sign-in page and comes back to Superset when correct credentials are provided) but it stucks in the final step.

# Custom Security Manager class
class CustomSsoSecurityManager(SupersetSecurityManager):
    def oauth_user_info(self, provider, response=None):  # noqa: ARG002
        me = self.appbuilder.sm.oauth_remotes[provider].get("openid-connect/userinfo")
        me.raise_for_status()
        data = me.json()
        logging.info("User info from Keycloak: %s", data)
        return {
            "username": data.get("preferred_username", ""),
            "first_name": data.get("given_name", ""),
            "last_name": data.get("family_name", ""),
            "email": data.get("email", ""),
            "role_keys": data.get("groups", []),
        }

# Set the custom security manager
CUSTOM_SECURITY_MANAGER = CustomSsoSecurityManager

# OAuth provider configuration for Keycloak
OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
    {
        'name': 'keycloak',
        'icon': 'fa-key',
        'token_key': 'access_token',  # Keycloak uses 'access_token' for the access token
        'remote_app': {
            'client_id': IAM_CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': IAM_CLIENT_SECRET,
            'client_kwargs': {
                'scope': 'openid profile email roles',
            },
            'server_metadata_url': KEYCLOAK_METADATA_URL,
            'api_base_url': KEYCLOAK_API_BASE_URL,
        },
    }
]


Please provide an explanation of how your code answers the question.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
